# Prevent url pop up over bottom navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I'm building a React app using `@material-ui`'s `BottomNavigationBar`. The bottom bar action component for Dashboard get's an input property `component={Link}` which is a component from `react-router-dom`. The action component has another component `to={"/main/dashboard"}`.

This probably makes the browser act as if this was a usual link and thus it shows the url pop up.

How do I hide the url label that pops up over my bottom navigation bar?

I added two images to make the problem clearer.

[image: Without mouse over] Bottom action bar without clicking it.

[image: Sample url popup]
Bottom action bar with url pop up after clicking a navigation bar button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `button` instead of `Link`, and then navigate with `history`, this way there will be no more url label.

The action component then has a `onClick={() => history.push('url')}`